# How can I randomize an entire string of 62 characters?

Tags: php

I have 62 base64 characters that I want to randomize. How can I do this using PHP? The string would be all letters, upper and lower case as well as numbers from 0-9.

The thing that is most important to me is that the entire string be evaluated before a return value is given. In other words, if I request a string of 8 characters in length and my string starts out like:

1234567890ABCDE..... I don't want to get the first 8 numbers randomized. It should randomize the entire string first, then return 8 characters from that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = '1234567890ABCDE...';

$string = substr(str_shuffle($string), 0, 8);
```

[str_shuffle](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.str-shuffle.php) randomizes the string, then [substr](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) takes the first 8 characters from it.

Comment: Thanks man. I was using  a for loop and rand(). Your solution was WAY better. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [str_shuffle](https://www.php.net/str_shuffle).

Comment: Thanks Yacoby, going there now.